# Call base class constructor after member constructor

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

I have the following class hierarchy, where the Base class depends on its derived class to supply it an argument in its constructor:

```
class Member
{
public:
    Member(int v);  
};

class Base
{
public:
    Base(const Member& m);  
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : m_(123), Base(m_) // <- here is the problem
    {
    }

private:
    Member m_;
};
```

The problem is, though, that in `Derived`'s constructor, the `Base` constructor gets called first, when `Derived`'s member variable `m_` which it depends on isn't initialized yet.
Is there a way to force the compiler to call the constructor of `m_` first or should I just rework my class hierarchy?

Comment: Could `Member m_` just be a (protected) member of `Base` that gets initialized in the base class constructor? Is there a reason to favor inheritance over composition?

Comment: in this particular case you could write `Derived() : Base(Member(123)), m_(123) {}` but I have the feeling that you went a step too far from your actual problem ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate initializing your member before the base class by making it it's own base class which you initialize first. You can wrap it in a simple class type and have `Derived` inherit privately from that type before `Base`. In the following example, `Derived` has a `Member _m;` which is initialized and then used to initialize `Base`.

```
class Member
{
public:
    Member(int) {}
};

class Base
{
public:
    Base(const Member&) {}
};

// The new wrapper
struct member_wrapper
{
    member_wrapper(int v) : m_(v) {}

    Member m_;
};


class Derived : private member_wrapper, public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : member_wrapper(123), Base(m_)
    { }
};
```

Though in this case, since `m_` is already a `class` type and `Derived` has no other members with that type, you can just inherit privately from `Member` directly. If you had a non-`class` type or multiple members of the same type that needed to be initialized before `Base` you would need to wrap them.

```
class Member
{
public:
    Member(int) {}
};

class Base
{
public:
    Base(const Member&) {}
};

class Derived : private Member, public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Member(123), Base(*this)
    { }
};
```